# How to confirm if some substrings from one file are contain in the other file?

Tags: python, string, file, substring

I have 2 files as follows and try to find which substring of file2 is in file1:

file1.txt:

> NP_001106283
>   MRIISRQIVLLFSGFWGLAMGAFPSSVQIGGLFIRNTDQEYTAFRLAIFLHNTSP
>   NP_001106697
>   MYLSRFLSIHALWVTVSSVMQPYPLVWGHYDLCKTQIYTEEGKVWD

file2.txt

> RIISRQIVLL
>    AABBCCDD
>    SRFLSIHAL
>    BBBBCCEE

Desired result:

> RIISRQIVLL
>    SRFLSIHAL

The code I have tried, but not work:

```
with open("file1.txt", mode="r") as file1, open("file2.txt", mode="r") as file2:
    data=file1.read()
    for line in file2:
        if line in data:
            print(line)
```

Any suggestion or help?
Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: replace 'if line if line in data:' try with  ' if line.strip() in data:' It should work

Answer (score 1):

just add line.strip() you code will work.

```
with open("xyz.txt", 'r') as file1, open("second.txt", 'r') as file2, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    data=file1.read()
    for line in file2:
        if line.strip() in data:            
            output.write(line)
```

I tried with

xyz.txt

```
NP_001106283
MRIISRQIVLLFSGFWGLAMGAFPSSVQIGGLFIRNTDQEYTAFRLAIFLHNTSP
NP_001106697
MYLSRFLSIHALWVTVSSVMQPYPLVWGHYDLCKTQIYTEEGKVWD
```

second.txt

```
RIISRQIVLL
AABBCCDD
SRFLSIHAL
BBBBCCEE
```

Output:

```
RIISRQIVLL
SRFLSIHAL
```

Comment: But if I want to write the output in another file, how can I do it?

Comment: @Eric code updated to write the output in another file.

Answer (score 0):

your data may containing \n at the end

```
with open("file1.txt", mode="r") as file1, open("file2.txt", mode="r") as file2:
    data=file1.read()

    for line in file2:

        if line.replace("\n", "") in data:
            print(line)
```

you can try to print line by following command to check actual text

```
print(repr(line))
```

Comment: No, you can iterate over an open file directly.

Comment: @KlausD., its corrected now !!!

Comment: Good job, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:
    lines_f1 = '-'.join(f1.read().split())
    lines_f2 = f2.read().split()
    for line in lines_f2:
        if line in lines_f1:
            print(line)
```

'-' is used as a separator so if '-' is contained in any string to be searched then you can use any other delimiter.

Comment: It also works, thank you